# Failure in adding value column in Panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data frame of tweets which I group in Dialogues and want to get index of turns for each Dialogue. So I create a new column of Index and add values in a for loop according to if it belongs to one Dialogue or another. When I evaluate the data frame's new column which is a Panda series I can see the new values being added but if I evaluate the data frame as a whole the values are still with the default value. Don't have any idea of how to debug this.

*** Ok so while I was creating a dummy data set to attach for this post, I realized that the problem is in a prior part of the code, in which I filter out the groups that don't have less than 8 records. When I comment this part of the code, the value gets updated correctly in the new column but when this part is present the column stays with the default value. 
I have realized that the code I have is not the best way of doing what I intend and that I should use apply and also with the first part of the code I get the number of turns of the dialogues so I could just use that to fill in the Index column but I would still like to know why the value is not being updated.

sample code:

```
# I created a table to get the counts of each Dialogues 
counts = df.groupby('Dialogue').count()
counts['Dialogue_'] = counts.index
counts_ = counts[['Dialogue_', 'id']]
counts = counts_[(counts_[['id']] > 8)["id"]]
count_id = counts.Dialogue_
df = df[df['Dialogue'].isin(count_id)]
#So if I comment the part above the Index column gets updated correctly

j=2
df["Index"] = int()
df["Index"].iloc[0]=1
#pd.Series(range(1,13))
for i in range(1, len(df["id"])):
    if (int(df["Dialogue"].iloc[i]) == int(df["Dialogue"].iloc[i - 1])):
        df["Index"][i] = j
        j += 1
    else:
        j=1
        df["Index"][i] = j
        j += 1


#Sample data

id  Dialogue    created_at
316 1   Sat Aug 06 01:44:03 +0000 2016
317 1   Tue Oct 31 22:11:33 +0000 2017
485 2   Tue Oct 31 22:27:38 +0000 2017
486 2   Tue Oct 31 22:33:11 +0000 2017
488 2   Tue Oct 31 21:33:48 +0000 2017
487 2   Tue Oct 31 22:52:37 +0000 2017
489 2   Tue Oct 31 22:25:31 +0000 2017
490 2   Tue Oct 31 22:28:50 +0000 2017
493 2   Tue Oct 31 21:18:55 +0000 2017
491 2   Tue Oct 31 23:07:41 +0000 2017
492 2   Wed Nov 01 15:10:21 +0000 2017
494 2   Sun Oct 29 16:56:47 +0000 2017
713862  2   Sun Oct 29 16:59:23 +0000 2017
495 2   Sun Oct 29 15:59:35 +0000 2017
496 2   Tue Oct 31 22:23:07 +0000 2017
498 3   Tue Oct 31 22:22:01 +0000 2017
499 3   Tue Oct 31 22:39:33 +0000 2017
500 3   Tue Oct 31 22:39:44 +0000 2017
501 3   Tue Oct 31 20:52:02 +0000 2017
507 3   Tue Oct 31 22:22:00 +0000 2017
502 3   Tue Oct 31 19:21:13 +0000 2017
503 3   Tue Oct 31 19:18:45 +0000 2017
504 3   Tue Oct 31 18:44:51 +0000 2017
2584875 3   Tue Oct 31 19:11:03 +0000 2017
```

So when I evaluate df["Index"] I see the correct number but when I see df the values remains as 0. How is that possible?

Comment: You should give some data and explain your needs.And I don't recommend that you use loops in dataframe.

Comment: just give some minmal code that one can paste and run, no idea what you have for `first_Process`